# How to create a generic typesafe HashMap by class type?

Tags: java, generics

I'd like to create a `HashMap` that maps specific class types to one single specific new object.

Later I want to pass the class type and get the reference to that specific object.
Simple example:

```
Map<Class<?>, ?> values = new HashMap<>();

public <T> t get(Class<T> type) {
    return values.get(type);
}


//pet and car do not share any interface or parent class
class Pet;
class Car;

//error: not applicable for arguments
values.put(Pet.class, new Pet());
values.put(Car.class, new Car());
```

usage:

```
values.get(Pet.class);
```

How can I create such a generic hashmap and lookup function accordingly?

Comment: Are you looking for Guava's [`ClassToInstanceMap`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#ClassToInstanceMap) ?

Comment: Great, probably this is what I'm trying to reinvent ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to store *some* type of object, if you want to be able to put anything else as `Object` in the map, so start off with this:

```
Map<Class<?>, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
```

This has to be done this way, because `?` is not a concrete object, but `Object` is, for the type the map stores.

So the following snippet works, without warnings:

```
Map<Class<?>, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put(Pet.class, new Pet());
values.put(Car.class, new Car());
```

Now the trick is to get objects, we do it as follows:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <T> T get(Class<T> clazz) {
    return (T)values.get(clazz);
}
```

Now *your goal* is to ensure that the map contains pairs that provide no errors on runtime. If you put a `new Car()` instance with `Car.class` , then you are going to get errors.

So the following example code:

```
    values = new HashMap<>();
    values.put(Pet.class, new Pet());
    values.put(Car.class, new Car());

    System.out.println("get(Pet.class).getClass() = " + get(Pet.class).getClass());
    System.out.println("get(Car.class).getClass() = " + get(Car.class).getClass());
```

will print:

```
get(Pet.class).getClass() = class testproject8.Pet
get(Car.class).getClass() = class testproject8.Car
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you are after a heterogeneous container. There is no easy way to create such a container in Java without any explicit casts.

I think the easiest way is to put your map in a class -

```
public class Container {
    private Map<Class<?>, Object> values = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> T put(Class<T> klass, T obj) {
        return klass.cast(values.put(klass, obj));
    }

    public <T> T get(Class<T> klass) {
        return klass.cast(values.get(klass));
    }
}
```

And use the class as follows -

```
Container c = new Container();
c.put(Pet.class, new Pet());
c.put(Car.class, new Car());
Pet p = c.get(Pet.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object` as the value type:

```
Map<Class<?>, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
```

You don't know the type of the values anyway.

Then, if you want to be sure that the object inserted via `put` is of the class that serves as key, you may create `safePut()` the following way:

```
public <T> T safePut(Class<T> key, T value) {
    return (T) values.put(key, value);
}
```